# Why Aster Image not showing (swir_4,5,6,7,9) bands in the area of interest in Google Earth Engine?

Tags: google-earth-engine, image, aster

When I want to download all bands of aster images, in Google Earth Engine, for AOI some bands not showing the phenomenon, and only the image has a black background, this problem occurs in the swir bands(4,5,6,7,8 and 9), are we can fix this issue?

```
var aoi = ee.Geometry.Polygon(
        [[[41.15269566368311, 37.83954900915779],
          [41.15269566368311, 37.487324683752526],
          [41.83934117149561, 37.487324683752526],
          [41.83934117149561, 37.83954900915779]]]);
var aster = ee.ImageCollection("ASTER/AST_L1T_003")
   .filter(ee.Filter.date('2021-01-01', '2022-01-01'))
   .median()
   .clip(aoi);

var falseColor = aster.select(['B3N', 'B02', 'B01']);
var falseColorVis = {
  min: 0.0,
  max: 255.0,
};

//var bands15 = aster.select(['B3N', 'B02', 'B01']); 
var bands30 = aster.select(['B04','B05','B06','B07','B08','B09']);
//var bands90 = aster.select(['B10','B11','B12','B13','B14']);

Map.centerObject(aoi);
Map.addLayer(aster,{},'image');

Map.addLayer(falseColor, falseColorVis, 'False Color');


Export.image.toDrive({ 
  image: bands30,
  description: 'aster_30',
  fileNamePrefix: 'aster_2022',
  folder: 'GEE_DATA',
  scale: 30, 
  maxPixels: 1e13, 
  region: aoi 
});
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/a2abe4ee83462fee9ed784dab7185c4d

Comment: https://lpdaac.usgs.gov/news/aster-user-advisory-updated-january-14-2009